# Issues with multiplication table output

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out the multiplication table and my function prints out one row at a time. 
It works fine alone, but when I run multitable(n) through a for loop, it prints out "None" at the end of each row.
Why is this happening and how do I get rid of it?

```
def multitable(n):
    for num in range (1,12+1):
        print(num*n,end = " ")

#multitable(1)
#multitable(2)

for n in range (1,12+1):
    print(multitable(n))
```

Comment: `(1,12+1)` is mostlikely not what you intended to type, more likely `(1,12, 1)`

Comment: @tomc I think what the OP is doing is a way to say "from 1 to 12 inclusive"

Comment: Why not have your function return the strings, instead of printing them? I would think that the former is better design than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
print(multitable(n))
```

with this:

```
multitable(n)
```

Your program is printing `None` because that's the value that `multitable()` is returning. If you don't want to see it, all you have to do is to avoid printing it.

Answer (score 1):

mutlitable(n) does not return anything and thus returns None, which you then print. Seperate the statements.

```
def multitable(n):
    for num in range (1,12+1):
        print(num*n,end = " ")

#multitable(1)
#multitable(2)

for n in range (1,12+1):
    multitable(n)
    print()
```

Comment: Why even keep the `print()` statement in there? It does nothing except add an extra blank line to the output.

Comment: I think that is for the format of the multiplication table, rather than one big line.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `return` value of the function, which you print out. If there is no return statement

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#return

Like the accepted answer `multitable(n)` will do the needful, otherwise return the function

```
for n in range (1,4):
    multitable(n)
    print()
```